# access denied when add new item in chrome browser sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, error

I use Chrome browser, When i add new item, i get informed Access denied:

> Access Denied
>
> An access request has been blocked due to one of the following
>   reasons: You do not have sufficient privileges to access this
>   destination Your corporate IT policies prohibit access to this content
>   or application McAfee Global Threat Intelligence has determined this
>   destination to have a suspicious or malicious reputation at this time
>   something in the connection that matches a threat defense signature
>   malware, spyware or other content should be blocked Please contact
>   your administrator if you feel this is incorrect.

When i use Firefox browser, with the same account, i can add new item sucessfull.
Please help me. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the antivirus extension or other extensions installed in your chrome

Click ( ≡ ) ,  "Tools", and then "Extensions"